# Inline-flex centering and gap issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center two divs with `display: inline-flex;` inside a block container, but somehow `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` doesn't work. Only text-align: center; works, but it shouldn't be like that (because I've read that with display: inline-flex; it should be align-items and justify-content) I guess? If my solution is correct, then can you tell me what's the difference?

Also, I want to get rid of that little gap between these two centered divs, but I've tried some solutions from the internet and none of them works. Why?

I'd be glad if you guys could help me out with both of my questions.

Here's the code example:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.child, .child2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: honeydew;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <h1> Test1.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <h1> Test2.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It will work if you use `display: flex` on container element. `align-items` and `justify-content` position flex items inside flex-container so you need to set `display: flex` on parent element.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child,
.child2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: honeydew;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <h1> Test1.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <h1> Test2.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like it solved the issue, but another one appeared: when the screen is scaled down to some point it should break the line of those 2 divs and display the second one under the first one like it did with my code. Is there any way to fix that or just with media queries?

Comment: There is a way, just add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to flex-container https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1519/

Comment: It will work if you use display: flex on (parent) container element ... all I needed ... thanks